# Minimum connection time at Riyadh on Saudi Airlines?

Tags: layovers, short-connections, saudi-airlines, ruh

I will be travelling from Kochi to London via Riyadh with Saudi Arabian Airlines.
Kochi to Riyadh flight lands around 10.15 AM and Riyadh to London flight departs around 11.55 AM.
I am unsure about which terminals these flights operate from.
Can someone please advise whether this time would be sufficient, and what will happen if the connecting flight is missed ? 
How is the service and punctuality of Saudi Airlines?

Comment: Is it one ticket?

Comment: It is purchased as a single ticket from Saudi Airlines.

Comment: Chitra, then it is ok, Saudia will handle that with no issues even if you didn't catch it. On-time performance is quite reliable with Saudia.

Answer (score 5):

SV775 COK-RUH arrives at terminal 2 according to [flightstats](http://www.flightstats.com). SV117 RUH-LHR also departs terminal 2 but I could only see that by searching google. According to [expertflyer](http://www.expertflyer.com/air/travelInformation.do) (requires subscription or free trial), the Minimum Connection Time (MCT) for an international to international connection at RUH is 1:30, however SV connections to SV at terminal 2 appear to have a shorter MCT of 1:00. In any case, as long as this is booked on one ticket, the airline will rebook you on a later flight if you miss your connection. You can look on flightstats for statistics relating to the likelihood you will miss your connection. A few days ago, SV775 arrived 2 hours late...